# LLM Question answer models for yes or no answers

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, nlp-question-answering

imagine I have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

# Positive and negative sentences
positive_sentences = [
    "I love this product!",
    "The weather is beautiful today.",
    "The team did an excellent job.",
    "She is a very talented musician."
]

negative_sentences = [
    "I am not satisfied with the service.",
    "The food was terrible at that restaurant.",
    "The movie was a complete disappointment.",
    "He made a lot of mistakes in the project."
]

# Combine positive and negative sentences
sentences = positive_sentences + negative_sentences

# Create a DataFrame with a "snippet" column
df = pd.DataFrame({'snippet': sentences})

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

I want to use a LLM model that answers the following question. Is the following sentence positive, negative or neutral?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
## installing the libraries:
import pandas as pd
from transformers import pipeline, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, RobertaForQuestionAnswering
import torch
from transformers import BertForQuestionAnswering, BertTokenizer

# Setting up the model and tokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad')

# Create a question answering pipeline
question_answerer = pipeline("question-answering", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    article = row["snippet"]  
    prompt = f"Is the following sentence positive, negative or neutral? {article}"

    result = question_answerer(question=prompt, context=article)

    # Check if "answer" key is in the result
    if "answer" in result:
        main_theme = result["answer"]
        print(f"Article {index+1} main theme: {main_theme}")
    else:
        print(f"Article {index+1} main theme not found in the result.")
```

Comment: Is this question a requirement and maybe just a placeholder? Is it enough when the model tells you the sentence is pos, neg, or neutral? When the answer to both questions is yes, you should look for a sentiment analysis model. There are plenty available at hf.

Comment: thanks for the comment @cronoik, you are right. This is perhaps a bad example since I mix it with sentiment analisis. What I am after is to develop a QA model with a yes or no answer to contrast different algorithms. For example, imagine a textblob sentiment algorithm gives me the right sentiment (groud truth), how accurate would Bert be by using it in the format of a QA model?

Comment: The classes you imported are for models that perform extractive QA. That means they will extract a span of the text you provide. Your input should therefore be similar to this: `[CLS] Is the sentence: {text} positive [SEP] Yes. No.`. But I doubt that will work because BERT and RoBERTa are not LLM like ChatGPT. We know that their extractive QA checkpoints are utterly domain-specific.  I suggest that you fine-tune your own model for your purposes. You could formulate it as a sequence classification task with two classes yes/no. Maybe also use LORA.

Comment: Or you switch to an actual LLM like Llama2 ;)

Comment: thanks, @cronoik for the answers! I will investigate further